# Firefox showing wrong favicon first time

Tags: html

I am having an issue with the favicon showing a wrong favicon in Firefox the first time but showing it right after a refresh. All other browsers are not having this issue. I am using the following:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/shared/img/favicon.ico">
```

Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: did you clear FF cache?

Comment: Could this possibly be  caching issue or maybe the link is incorrect and linking locally?

Comment: Two questions: Does the `<link>` appear after lots of other markup in the head? And, does your server have a `favicon.ico` file in the docroot? Is this the wrong one?